# Отправка писем к нескольким получателям через цикл

Tags: php, codeigniter, smtp, sendmail, phpmailer

Отправка писем через SMTP. Использую EMAIL класс от codeigniter 3. Проблема в том что когда через цикл отправляю только к первому, письмо идет. а к другим нет. вот код:

```
    $message = file_get_contents($_FILES['text']['tmp_name']);
        foreach($address as $ad_value) {
            sleep(15);
            $this->email->to($ad_value);
            $this->email->subject('Заявка');
            $this->email->message($message);
            $this->email->send();
        }
```

$ad_value --- тут массив почт. их 10 пока что. Никак не получается всем отправить, цикл на первом же походу останавливается.Отправляю с локального сервера XAMPP. Что посоветуете? Как можно решить?

Comment: официальная [документация](http://codeigniter3.info/guide/libraries/email#CI_Email::clear) для использования в цикле рекомендует в начале использовать очистку `$this->email->clear();` попробуйте. также для отладки советую использовать [`print_debugger`](http://codeigniter3.info/guide/libraries/email#CI_Email::print_debugger)

Comment: @NikolajSarry использую все что вы написали, так же первому только приходит письмо.

Comment: а как выглядит массив $ad_value?

Comment: "массив почт. их 10 пока что" так массив почт в $address или в $ad_value?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov в $address

Comment: Тут скорей всего надо или в каждом цикле создавать новый объект email или без цикла подставить массив получателей в to

Comment: @DmitryKozlov да так получается, но как рассылка же идет и получатель может увидеть кому еще помимо его отправлено, так не хочется, по одному надо. Чтоб цикл по одному проставлял с задержкой. Sleep тоже не помогает

Comment: Тогда после send сделайте $this->email->clear()